# List the names of the NAs in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called df and I have 10 variables inside this df.

df contains a list of countries which are connected to their gdp, unemployment level, and whether they have been colonised as a (TRUE) etc.

For each variable gdp, unemp level and colonised I know there's a number of NAs.

Is there a command where I can list the names of the countries where they have NAs. e.g.: if the UK has NA for gdp, but has unemp and colonised and France has gdp, unemp but NA for colonised.

Is there a command which will bring a list of the UK and France because they have NAs?

My data:

```
destination                 origin sum gdp.diff unemployment.diff
1     Albania             Azerbaijan   2       27          8.467610
2     Albania                  Congo   1      -21                NA
3     Albania Dem. Rep. of the Congo   1      -80         13.437610
4     Albania                Eritrea  21      -66                NA
5     Albania Iran (Islamic Rep. of) 279        5          2.997610
6     Albania                   Mali   1      -68          6.137609
```

So I need Albania to appear in the list because is has an NA for unemp.diff

Comment: Can you show few lines of data and expected output

Comment: `foo <- data.frame(f = c("a","b","c"),g = c(1,NA,3)); foo[["f"]][is.na(asd[["g"]])]` 
Instead of explaining your data frame by words, do it by a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using complete.cases:

```
#dummy data
df <- data.frame(country = letters[1:3],
                 gdp = c(1,NA,2),
                 unemployment = c(1,2,3),
                 colonised = c(T,F,NA))
df
#   country gdp unemployment colonised
# 1       a   1            1      TRUE
# 2       b  NA            2     FALSE
# 3       c   2            3        NA

df[ !complete.cases(df), ]
#   country gdp unemployment colonised
# 2       b  NA            2     FALSE
# 3       c   2            3        NA

# check for NAs on one column
df[ is.na(df$gdp), ]
#   country gdp unemployment colonised
# 2       b  NA            2     FALSE
```

Comment: I have too many observations to show on one page so I lose most of the information. Is there not something like  df$gdp list the nas ?